# Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.tvalue5webservice.com only from intellij but it works from SOAP UI

Tags: intellij-idea, soap-client

I am trying to consume the soap service from **[www.tvalue5webservice.com](http://www.tvalue5webservice.com)**. I tried sending soap POST request to **http://www.tvalue5webservice.com/webservices/tve.asmx** from SOAP UI and it worked. I am trying the same SOAP request hardcoded in the spring boot java code running in my local intellij and getting unknown-host exception.

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: [www.tvalue5webservice.com](http://www.tvalue5webservice.com)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337) ~[na:na]
at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:207) ~[feign-core-11.7.jar:na]
at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:104) ~[feign-core-11.7.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119) ~[feign-core-11.7.jar:na]
... 109 common frames omitted

We are using open-feign-api for http request.

I have proxy running in my system, I could be able to connect Azure which means my proxy is set properly.

Can anybody help me where would be issue?

Thank you,
Adithyan

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to IP COnfig. You have to add proxy setting to allow this transaction...